# Why does BETWEEN use a btree index but "element is contained by" range operator (<@) does not?

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan

I've got a table with a `utc timestamptz` which has a "btree" index on the `utc` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(utc timestamptz)

CREATE INDEX ix_foo_utc ON foo (utc);
```

This table contains about 500 million rows of data.

When I filter `utc` using `BETWEEN`, the query planner uses the index as expected:

```sql
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
   utc
FROM foo
WHERE
    utc BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2031-02-15'
;

QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=3048368.34..11836322.22 rows=143671392 width=8) (actual time=12447.905..165576.664 rows=150225530 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: ((utc >= '2020-12-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (utc <= '2031-02-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 543231
Heap Blocks: exact=43537 lossy=1818365
->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_foo_utc  (cost=0.00..3012450.49 rows=143671392 width=0) (actual time=12436.236..12436.236 rows=150225530 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((utc >= '2020-12-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (utc <= '2031-02-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning time: 0.127 ms
Execution time: 172335.517 ms
```

But if I run the same query using a range operator, the index isn't used:

```sql
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
   utc
FROM quotation.half_hour_data
WHERE
    utc <@ tstzrange('2020-12-01', '2031-02-15')
;

QUERY PLAN
Gather  (cost=1000.00..9552135.30 rows=2556133 width=8) (actual time=0.179..145303.094 rows=150225530 loops=1)
Workers Planned: 2
Workers Launched: 2
->  Parallel Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..9295522.00 rows=1065055 width=8) (actual time=5.321..117837.452 rows=50075177 loops=3)
"Filter: (utc <@ '[""2020-12-01 00:00:00+00"",""2031-02-15 00:00:00+00"")'::tstzrange)
Rows Removed by Filter: 120333718
Planning time: 0.069 ms
Execution time: 153384.494 ms
```

I would have expected the query planner to realise that these are doing the same operation (albeit that `<@` is right-hand exlusive and `BETWEEN` is inclusive.)

So why are these query plans so different? (Forget about asking why the sequential scan query completes more quickly??!!)

---

My Postgres version:

```
"PostgreSQL 10.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An index can only support operators that belong to its *operator class*.

```
SELECT ao.amoplefttype::regtype,
       op.oprname,
       ao.amoprighttype::regtype
FROM pg_opfamily AS of
   JOIN pg_am AS am ON of.opfmethod = am.oid
   JOIN pg_amop AS ao ON of.oid = ao.amopfamily
   JOIN pg_operator AS op ON ao.amopopr = op.oid
WHERE am.amname = 'btree'
  AND ao.amoplefttype = 'timestamptz'::regtype;

       amoplefttype       | oprname |        amoprighttype        
--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------
 timestamp with time zone | <       | date
 timestamp with time zone | <=      | date
 timestamp with time zone | =       | date
 timestamp with time zone | >=      | date
 timestamp with time zone | >       | date
 timestamp with time zone | <       | timestamp without time zone
 timestamp with time zone | <=      | timestamp without time zone
 timestamp with time zone | =       | timestamp without time zone
 timestamp with time zone | >=      | timestamp without time zone
 timestamp with time zone | >       | timestamp without time zone
 timestamp with time zone | <       | timestamp with time zone
 timestamp with time zone | <=      | timestamp with time zone
 timestamp with time zone | =       | timestamp with time zone
 timestamp with time zone | >=      | timestamp with time zone
 timestamp with time zone | >       | timestamp with time zone
(15 rows)
```

There is no `<@` operator in there, so a B-tree index cannot support this operator.

GIN indexes can support `<@`, but not with the constant on the right side.

You will have to rewrite the query and use `BETWEEN`.

Remark: There is not a fundamental reason why it is like that, it is just how indexes work in PostgreSQL. It is even possible to write an *optimizer support function* that would do exactly that, but your use case is so exotic that PostgreSQL doesn't want to spend optimizer time and development effort on it.